# Pass ulimit to dockerd

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes, ulimit

I'm new in kubernetes and I'm trying to deploy an elasticsearch on it.
Currently, I have a problem with the number of file descriptor required by elasticsearch and allow by docker.

```
[1]: max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]
```

So to fix that I have tried 3 different ways:

## way 1

From the docker documentation, dockerd should use the system value as default value.

1. set `/etc/security/limits.con`f with `* - nofile 65536`
2. reboot
3. execute `ulimit -Hn && ulimit -Sn` return return 65536 twice
4. execute `docker run --rm centos:7 /bin/bash -c 'ulimit -Hn && ulimit -Sn'` (should return 65536 twice but no, return 4096 and 1024 )

## way 2

1. add `--default-ulimit nofile=65536:65536` to `/var/snap/microk8s/current/args/dockerd`
2. reboot
3. execute `docker run --rm centos:7 /bin/bash -c 'ulimit -Hn && ulimit -Sn'` (should return 65536 twice but no return 4096 and 1024)

## way 3

1. add

   "default-ulimit" : {
           "nofile":{
               "Name":" nofile",
               "Hard":" 65536",
               "Soft":" 65536"
       }
   }

   to `/var/snap/microk8s/354/args/docker-daemon.json`
2. execute `systemctl restart  snap.microk8s.daemon-docker.service`
3. execute `journalctl -u snap.microk8s.daemon-docker.service -f` will return `unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /var/snap/microk8s/354/args/docker-daemon.json: the following directives don't match any configuration option: nofile`

The only way I found for set the ulimit is to pass `--ulimit nofile=65536:65536` to the docker run command. But I cannot do that inside my kubernetes statesfullset config.

So do you know how I can solve this problem ?
I didn't somethings wrong here ?

Thanks in advance for your help

ps: I'm on ubuntu 18.0.1 with docker 18.06.1-ce and microk8s installed with snap

Comment: aren't you using ELK images? I thought they had correct ulimit already

Comment: Yes, I have tried with `docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.5.4` and also with helm chart from [elastic](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/tree/master/elasticsearch) and the [official one](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/elasticsearch). And with all of them I have the same trouble....

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but if someone has this problem too, you can add this line to `/var/snap/microk8s/current/args/containerd-env`:

```
ulimit -n 65536
```

Then stop/start microk8s to enable this fix. If you execute command `docker run --rm centos:7 /bin/bash -c 'ulimit -Hn && ulimit -Sn'` you can see 65536 twice

More information on Microk8s Github issue [#253](https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/253). Microk8s has merge a fix for this, it may will be soon available on a release.